# How do I solve this FPS steep frame rate drop when gaming on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, troubleshooting, steam, games

Relevant specs from neofetch:

OS = Linux Mint 21.1 x86_64 /
Host = H310M H 2.0 /
Kernel = 5.15.0-72-generic /
DE = Xfce 4.16 /
CPU = Intel i5-8400 (6) @ 4.000GHz /
GPU = NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti /
Memory = 2381MiB / 15944MiB

Footage of the issue with mangohud (top-left): https://youtu.be/7pjmCjEqaTc

**I have had this issue across a few linux distros**, some would cause a system-wide stutter and others would have drops in frame rate such as in the video. The one thing these cases had in common was that I would always observe the CPU usage going up as it occurred. These drops in performance have always happened at intervals and are consistent throughout all gameplay, lasting around 20 to 30 seconds, then operating normally for the same length of time.

With mangohud enabled on my game I saw that **the CPU usage went up as the GPU went down**, which leads me to believe that this might be some hardware related issue. The weird thing is that when I first installed this OS, the problem seemed to have disappeared, now it's back. This makes me unsure if this is really hardware issue or software related.

This happens with every game I play now, be it on Steam or a different launcher, using proton / wine or a game native to linux. Interestingly, when playing the game Deep Rock Galactic and observing the task manager, the CPU usage went from 10% to 60% for the Steam app instead of the game itself. I'm not sure what that means.

How can I determine if this issue is caused by hardware or software? Is there a solution? I can share more information if it is needed.

**EDIT:** I have already tried changing the driver version. I've used the nvidia drivers 530, 515 and 470, same problem on each one. I have also tried changing the shader pre-cache settings on Steam.

I actually had *another 1050 Ti GPU from an older computer*. I put it in my computer and it ran a bit worse than my newer one but *the frame rate problem still persisted*. I also removed the GPU completely and ran Minecraft on **integrated graphics**, *the problem persisted still*.

As far as I can tell, this problem doesn't occur while playing on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the common denominator: Linux updates. More precisely, **updating the Linux kernel**.

See, every time I install a new app through the terminal, I am advised to update my system first, just so there won't be any dependency issues later on. Without really thinking about it, I install all the updates, and every once in a while, that comes with a new kernel version.

Well, after changing my kernel version around for a bit, I have been able to make the problems stop completely with a few specific ones. Below, I will specify issues I have been able to observe with each one I tested.

`kernel 5.15.0-56`, this came installed with the OS by default. The frame rate for gaming is not very optimized, but the sudden steep frame drop and audio stuttering **did not occur on this version**.

`kernel 5.15.0-69`, this version was more optimized than the previous one and had negligible frame rate issues. **I consider this to be the best version of this kernel**.

`kernel 5.15.0-72`, ***here is where the big issues began***. Starting in this version, my CPU usage was elevated when gaming and sometimes even when watching videos. My GPU usage would drop drastically resulting in frames dipping from 100+ to as low as 12.

`kernel 5.15.0-73`, ***it gets even worse***. In this version the stuttering was system-wide and unbearable. It affected every single game I ran, no matter the graphics. By far the weirdest symptom was the fact that **in this version my monitor wouldn't even turn on when booting**, and would only do so when rebooting.

`kernel 5.19.0-43`, this version of this kernel had the same issues as the `5.15.0-72`, almost exactly. In this particular case, my frames were high into the 100 range, but would only drop to 30 or slightly below.

Finally, `5.15.0-25` **is the one I use**. The frame rate is well optimized and the usage of CPU and GPU is normal. All is as it should be.

I don't entirely understand *why* the kernel has this impact on my system, but after running numerous tests and thoroughly examining the results, I can safely say that this was the root cause of the issue. When in doubt, try changing the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System Settings` in Administration section find `Driver Manager`. Choose the newer (or older) video driver.

Comment: I sort of forgot to mention that I have already tried to change the driver version. I will add that as an edit.

Comment: I have also used the 390 nvidia driver and the nouveau driver. In the case of the former, steam games didn't even want to turn on because of some x server problem and the latter runs as good as not having a GPU at all.

Comment: I'm considering trying out some apps to change the GPU clock or something to try and mitigate the issue. Alternatively, maybe there's a way to go back and reinstall the OS to its original state without losing my apps and projects.

Comment: I also cleared my downloads cache on Steam, in case that may have contributed to the issue. It didn't fix things.